# Confirm dialog jquery MVC3 Helper methods

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-ui-dialog

I am creating a confirm dialog box in one of my MVC views. Basically I wawnt to display the exact same information in the dialog before the information is submitted to the server.

In my view I have something similar to the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop2)

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="submitFunction();" />

<div id="divConfirmDialog" title="Confirm Dialog">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Prop1)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Prop2)
</div>
```

In `document.ready` function, I initialize  the `divConfirmDialog` as a jQuery dialog. I open the dialog on the submit button click event.

I do not see the changes that I have made to the textboxes inside my dialog. How would I go about in seeing those changes when the dialog opens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayFor()` method renders text for the value of the property *when the page loads*.

I would change the html to something like this:

```
<div id="divConfirmDialog" title="Confirm Dialog">
    <span class="prop1-display"></span>
    <span class="prop2-display"></span>
</div>
```

Then in your `submitFunction()`, you can move the values from the textboxes to the spans.

Comment: got it working with a similar approach. Just wanted to find out if there is any other alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Here is another way to do this,

```
<div id="divConfirmDialog" title="Confirm Dialog">
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Prop1,new {@class="prop1-display"})
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Prop2,new {@class="prop1-display"})
</div>
```